# Can Set-WebBinding change the protocol from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: powershell, iis

I can use [Set-WebBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/set-webbinding?view=winserver2012-ps) to change the port of a given binding, but can I use it to change from http on port 80 to https on port 443 or vice versa?

I tried with this command but it fails because it doesn't recognize `-PropertyName Protocol`:

```
Set-WebBinding -Name 'Default Web Site' -BindingInformation '127.0.0.1:80:localhost'  -PropertyName Port -Value 443 -PropertyName Protocol -Value 'https'
```

Or should I use `Remove-WebBinding` and then `New-WebBinding` to make such a change?

Comment: `Set-*` cmdlets will typically overwrite previous values.  Do you know if protocol is a valid property on the binding?

Comment: No, and I couldn't find it in the docs. I think @boxdog is right (the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to remove the existing binding with `Remove-WebBinding` and re-create it with `New-WebBinding`, which allows you to supply protocol, port, etc